# url is showing in page not found error in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created an endpoint and registered it in `urls.py`. When I try to hit the endpoint I get a `404` error but on the `404` page the url is shown as one of the patterns django tried to match. Stumped.

api.py

```
class UpdateLast(viewsets.GenericViewSet, UpdateModelMixin):

    def get(self):
        return XYZModel.objects.all()

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            with transaction.atomic():
                for key, value in request.data:
                    if key == 'tic':
                        XYZModel.objects.filter(ticker=request.data['tic']).filter(trail=True).update(
                            last_high=Case(
                                When(
                                    LessThan(F('last_high'),
                                             request.data['high']),
                                    then=Value(request.data['high'])),
                                default=F('last_high')
                            )
                        )
```

urls.py (this is inside the app)

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/dsetting', DViewSet, 'dsetting')
router.register('api/update-last-high', UpdateLast, 'update-last-high')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

urls.py (main)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('my_app.urls')),
```

When I hit the end-point `api/update-last-high` I get a 404 page.

On that page the exact end-point is shown as a pattern that django tried to match.

> ^api/update-last-high/(?P[^/.]+)/$ [name='update-last-high-detail']

> ^api/update-last-high/(?P[^/.]+).(?P[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='update-last-high-detail']

Comment: Why are you using the `router` in the app's urls.py?- why not just copy the same format as the main urls.py?

Answer (score 1):

```
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/dsetting', DViewSet, 'dsetting')
router.register('api/update-last-high', UpdateLast, 'update-last-high')

# you forgot to include the router.urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. I forgot to add that part here in the question. I have rechecked and added. Editing the question. The 404 error clearly shows the `url` I am looking for.

Comment: Very strange, if I change the `viewsets.GenericViewSet` to `viewsets.ModelViewSet` I can get to the endpoint. Time for some more reading.